# Django SQSError: 413 Request Entity Too Large

Tags: django

I'm getting the following error from the code below:

**SQSError: SQSError: 413 Request Entity Too Large**

The file I'm uploading is only 445k.

How can I resolve this error? Thank you.

**task.py**

```
@task
def import_csv(filename):
    ContactCSVModel.import_from_file(filename)
```

**view.py**

```
def upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
            filename = request.FILES['file']
            import_csv.delay(filename)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQS files cannot be 445kB.

The maximum size is **64kB**.

Please see Amazon's [FAQ for the SQS service](http://aws.amazon.com/sqs/faqs/):

> Amazon SQS messages can contain up to 64 KB of text data, including XML, JSON and unformatted text.

You more than likely want to use S3, [Amazon's file storage service](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/), where files can be up to 2GB.